# How do I represent dictionary of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I need a data structure to store the following data (I am using a dictionary to represent it):

```
{  {1:{2:3.4,  3:5.6,  4:7.8}},
   {2:{3:6.4,  4:66.6, 5:64.8}} ,
   {3:{4:33.4, 5:5.46, 6:72.8}} 
}
```

How do I represent such data in Python?

Currently I have this data in lists:

```
A = [[3.4,5.6,7.8], [6.4,66.6,64.8], [33.4,5.46,72.8]]
```

representing the value for each key. For example, the first list in `A` contains value for Item1 with respective Item2, Item3, Item4 (which again need to be a key(nested)). Same way the second list representing the value for Item2 with respect to Item3, Item4, Item5.

I am new to Python, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What you've shown isn't a dictionary of dictionaries, it's a _set_ of dictionaries of dictionaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're showing there is a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) of 1-item dictionaries - which can't exist in Python, because the elements of sets must be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable), and dictionaries aren't. However, a dictionary of dictionaries is perfectly straightforward to create:

```
{
    1: {2: 3.4, 3: 5.6, 4: 7.8},
    2: {3: 6.4, 4: 66.6, 5: 64.8},
    3: {4: 33.4, 5: 5.46, 6: 72.8}
}
```

Notice that the individual items in the outer dictionary aren't enclosed in braces.

Comment: Or, if you really did want the top level to be a sequence of 1-element dictionaries of dictionaries, you could put them in a list instead of a set… or a `sortedcollection.SortedCollection` or a `sortedcontainers.SortedList` or anything else that doesn't require immutable/hashable elements… but yeah, this is probably what the OP wants.